# Block a domain name from accessing my server

Tags: linux, ddos

I am facing a weired issue, my site is under attack, upon further checking i found that a particular domain is the one hitting my site/server. I blocked the IP of that culprit domain but it keeps sending requests on apache from different IP. Seems Culprit domain is on CDN etc. How can i put a block based on Domain name, instead of IP? CSF and IPtables has no such options. Please help

Comment: There is no such thing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton no such thing with iptables, true. But Aun: something like [iptables limits](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html) or even [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) might work.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "a domain is hitting my site" ? What do you see on the network or your logfiles ? Networks use IP and TCP or UDP on top of it. At these levels there is no "domain", only numbers. What traffic do you get?